# CSS Alternate color rows in dynamic table

Tags: css, dynamic, colors, css-tables

I'm using Dreamweaver and I want to color the rows of a dynamic table alternately. I can't seem to find any answers that work for me or that I understand. Could you give a sample CSS on how to do it? Explanations would help because I'm not confident in coding yet.

I'm using the Chrome browser.

Comment: please post what you have tried so far

Comment: hi. have nothing so far.just the page with dynamic table.simple demos would do.

Comment: thanks.where should i put that? in the css file?

Comment: check sujansh answer below. you put those in a linked css file or in a style block. i advise you to first go over the tutorials [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/) though.

Comment: got it working.  i stumbled upon that kind of code before but this time it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this to your css and it should work with all the modern browsers:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#eee;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Us e`nth-child`  http://jsfiddle.net/37bv1s14/

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>aa</td>
    <td>sadfdf</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>aa</td>
    <td>sadfdf</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>aa</td>
    <td>sadfdf</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>aa</td>
    <td>sadfdf</td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
table{
border:1px solid;
}

tr:nth-child(even){
background-color:green;
}
tr:nth-child(odd){
background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I generate a table using PHP, I use two (or more) CSS classes that are applied to the  tags of the table I want formatted.

`#my_table tr.r0 td {
    background-color: #123;
}`

`#my_table tr.r1 td {
    background-color: #456;
}`

In other words, the two CSS statements above mean: set background color of any `<td>` in a `<tr>` with class r0/r1 to #123/#456, only in table with id #my_table.

When you generate the rows of your table, you can set a counter that always increase by 1 every row (useful if your row generation have weird conditions that can prevent some rows to appear or generate a variable number of rows) and I use the modulo 2 (`% 2`) of the counter to decide if the row is even or odd. Even rows yield 0 and odd rows yield 1.

`echo '<tr class="r' . ($counter % 2) . '">';`

This lets you have any number of types of colors for rows.

Or, if you only have 2 row colors, you can use a variable that is set to 0 initially, and toggle between 0 and 1 every time you generate a row, like this:

`$counter = !$counter;`

Or use C-style if-then-else construct (less readability):

`$counter = $counter ? 0 : 1;`

Answer (score -3):

I updated this to provide a better example by showing an actual HTML page.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#eeeeee");
      $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Cat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Dog</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Mouse</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I updated my answer to provide more information.  It works in modern browsers and as you can see it's easy to do.   If you build web pages and haven't tried jQuery, then you are missing out on a great tool.

Comment: Not sure this is a good answer, because 1) it does not constrain itself to the very reasonable parameters of the question, 2) isn't necessary, more efficient, better standards-compliant, etc and 3) includes no explanation.